# If the invariant curves of two sub-manifolds are transversal, does this imply that the sub-manifolds are transversal?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, invariance, submanifold, transversality

Trying to determine the following:

> If the invariant curves of two sub-manifolds are transversal, does this imply that the sub-manifolds are transversal?

An example I have of invariant curves, are invariant hyperbola. In special relativity $\Delta s^2 = \Delta x^2 - c \Delta t^2$ is an invariant quantity, which is in the form of a hyperbola.

My attempt: If the invariant curves of two sub-manifolds are transversal then the tangent spaces of the sub-manifolds are transversal, implying that the sub-manifolds are transversal. I also need help with the correct notation.

I have "Intro to Manifolds" by Tu, and "Semi-Riemannian Geometry" by O'Neill but I didn't find the answer in them.

Please leave a comment. Thanks.

Comment: What is "an invariant curve of a submanifold"?

Comment: In special relativity $\Delta s^2 = \Delta x^2 - c \Delta t^2$ is an invariant quantity, and has the form of a hyperbola so the hyperbola are invariant

Comment: One usually does not talk about "a quantity" as having a geometric form. The set of points where a quantity is equal to something has a form. However, for the flat Minkowski space-time the set of point where the interval has a fixed value is a 3D hyperboloid. In particular, it is not a curve. With all this in mind, could you try to explain again and in a bit more detail what you mean by an "invariant curve of a submanifold"?

Comment: Comment independent of all this “invariant curve” stuff: This is all completely vague, but most likely dimensions make the transversality question meaningless. Two curves in $\Bbb R^3$ can be transverse only if they are disjoint. If these curves fill up surfaces, then the surfaces must also be disjoint (or else curves through a point of intersection could not be transverse) and hence are also transverse “by default.” The whole question is just completely vague.

Comment: @Max I'm dealing with $\Bbb R^{1,1}$ so the invariant hyperbola are curves in this case. I am going to write a new question and provide links to both of them. I figured out how to phrase everything.

Comment: @Max new question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3881246/transversal-invariant-hyperbolas-form-manifold