# Proving semi-Riemannian submanifolds are transversal

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, semi-riemannian-geometry, transversality

Recently I asked: [Invariant curves...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3880588/if-the-invariant-curves-of-two-sub-manifolds-are-transversal-does-this-imply-th)

Let $\Bbb R^{1,1}$ be a semi-Riemannian manifold called Minkowski-space. Consider the invariant timelike hyperbolas of the lower branch (rectangular hyperbolas).

$\varphi:\Bbb R^{1,1}\to\Bbb R^{1,1}_+$ with $\varphi(x,y)=(e^x,e^y)$ is a diffeomorphism. The invariant timelike hyperbola of the lower branch map to $(0,1)^2.$

Let $\Bbb R^{1,1}$ be another copy of Minkowski-space. Consider the invariant spacelike hyperbolas of the lower branch.

Use a diffeomorphism $\psi:\Bbb R^{1,1}\to\Bbb R^{1,1}$ with $\psi(x,y)=(-e^{-x},e^y).$ The invariant spacelike hyperbola of the lower branch map to $(-1,0)^2.$

Translate the invariant spacelike hyperbola to $(0,1)^2.$ Now the invariant timelike "hyperbola"  of the lower branch are transversal to the invariant spacelike "hyperbola" of the lower branch, in $(0,1)^2.$

In pink are the invariant spacelike hyperbola and in bluish-green are the invariant timelike hyperbola:

[image]

> How do you prove this transversality?

> Doesn't the region in $(0,1)^2$ form a manifold? How can one formalize this manifold?

In order to prove the transversality of the invariant spacelike and timelike "hyperbola" I need to prove that the tangent spaces of each generate the ambient space. So for submanifolds of $M$ being $S$ and $T,$ standing for invariant spacelike and timelike "hyperbola" respectively, I need to prove that:

$$\forall p\in S \cap T,~ T_pM=T_pS + T_pT $$

I believe that the tangent spaces span a space that is isometric to $\Bbb R^{1,1},$ hence the ambient manifold must be at least isometric to $\Bbb R^{1,1}$ in the bounded region $(0,1)^2.$

I'm having trouble connecting all the dots and writing down the rigorous proof though.